# How can I implement FocusListener of JDatePicker?

Tags: java, swing, jdatechooser, focuslistener

I want to perform some function in `FocusEvent` of `JDatePicker`. I am using below code for implementing `FocusListener`.

```
Properties p = new Properties();
p.put("text.today", "Today");
p.put("text.month", "Month");
p.put("text.year", "Year");
UtilDateModel model = new UtilDateModel();
Calendar today=Calendar.getInstance();
Date todayDate=new Date();
today.setTime(todayDate);
model.setDate(today.get(Calendar.YEAR), today.get(Calendar.MONTH), today.get(Calendar.DATE));
model.setSelected(true);
JDatePanelImpl datePanel =new JDatePanelImpl(model, p);
JDatePickerImpl datePicker = new JDatePickerImpl(datePanel,new DateLabelFormatter());

datePicker.addFocusListener(new FocusListener() {

    @Override
    public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("fcus lost");
    }

    @Override
    public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("focus gained");
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                //repaint();
                displayImage(categoryAttributeObj,imGroupObj);
            }

        });
    }
});
```

This code not working. Is any error in this code?

Comment: *"I any error in this code"* - Really, like what?

Comment: Perhaps, instead of trying to listen to a focus change event, you should attach a `ChangeListener` to the model

Comment: I am using jdatepicker.1.3.4.jar for implementing datepicker.Is changeListener is avaiable in this JDatePicker Class

Comment: That's because it's part of the model (`UtilDateModel`)

Comment: This only work when state change of DatePicker .I want to implement functionality when getting focus on Datepicker.

Comment: Well, as far as I can see, you'll need a good amount of luck to make it work, as it doesn't seem to be a feature that the developer consider important

Comment: Can we use JXDatePicker instead of JDatePicker.Is there any problem for using JXDatepicker.

Comment: I've run through the code, there is simply no way to access the fields via the api. Personally, I prefer SwingLabs SwingX's JXDatePicker for this, and other, reasons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not a particular fan of `JDatePicker`, for a number of personal reasons.

You could implement your own version which provided you with the functionality your after or you could try SwingLabs, SwingX `JXDatePicker` instead, for example

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.FocusAdapter;
import java.awt.event.FocusEvent;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import org.jdesktop.swingx.JXDatePicker;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }

    public Main() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {
            add(new JButton("Before"));
            JXDatePicker picker = new JXDatePicker();
            picker.getEditor().addFocusListener(new FocusAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {
                    System.out.println("You have foucs");
                }
            });
            add(picker);
            add(new JButton("After"));
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Property(Change)Support/Listener

Comment: @mKorbel To what?  `PropertyChangeListener` is about as good as adding a `ChangeListener` to the `UtilDateModel` for `JDatePicker`, which we've established isn't sufficient for the OP's needs

Comment: there is/are implemented Property(Change)Support/Listener, because whats reason to add FocusListener to derived  JSpinner / JFormattedTextField, maybe only if the value changes then is reason for firing an event,

Comment: @mKorbel I don't know why the OP wants to do something when the field is focused, I just know they don't care about monitoring state changes.  Go ask the OP why they need this particular feature :P

Comment: agree as aside Focus is there implemented and I think (most popular JXxxDate/Calendar) that correctly, because in most cases Selection with Caret works (last Caret possition is top)

Comment: I'm awaiting that, missing there, in your answer == Focus works with/for derived  JSpinner / J(Formatted)TextField only, that is fully qualified nonsence

Comment: @mKorbel Sorry, I miss your point.  The example is runnable and clearly demonstrates that a `focusGained` event is triggered when focus moves into the field.  The `JXDatePicker` exposes the `JFormattedField`.  Would you suggest trying to add it directly to the `JXDatePicker`, cause that would be my personal preference, assuming it worked

Comment: I already added JXDatepicker and all worked fine for me. In my application in component FocusEvent I want to highlight the value of that component in Image.So I ask this question.